# How log to event properties without placing them in the message?

Tags: c#, json, .net, logging, nlog

I'm current using NLog to log into Json format. I want to log event args in my logs under "eventProperties" without them being included in the message attribute.

Current nlog.config:

```
<target name="jsonFile" xsi:type="Console">
  <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
    <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    <attribute name="eventProperties" encode="false" >
      <layout xsi:type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="6"/>
    </attribute>
  </layout>
</target>
```

Currently call it with:

```
_logger.LogDebug(20, "Doing hard work! {logInfo}", t2);
```

Which logs the following:

```
{ "time": "2022-05-19 08:24:15.1395", "level": "DEBUG", "message": "Doing hard work! Test", "eventProperties": { "logInfo": {"MyProperty":"Hello2", "MyProperty2":"Testing2", "MyModel":{"MyProperty":"Hello", "MyProperty2":"Testing"}}, "EventId": 20 } }
```

However, I want to be able to log with the below without it stopping t2 from being logged in the eventProperties section of the JSON:

```
_logger.LogDebug(20, "Doing hard work!", t2);
```

and output for the message property to not include `test` in it anymore:

```
"message": "Doing hard work!"
```

How can I go about removing the property from the message without it being removed from eventProperties?

EDIT - I'm using the Microsoft ILogger Abstraction for `.LogDebug()`

Comment: Are you using NLog API or Microsoft Logging Abstraction? Looks like MS ILogger API.

Comment: @Fildor - I'm using the Microsoft ILogger abstraction

Comment: Asking, because answers may be different. I just found some ideas for NLog API, like using the MDLC and using the related template ... which doesn't seem to translate to MS Logging API very well. But I upvoted to attrackt people that are hopefully more proficient with NLog than I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the message-template (instead of the formatted message) using `raw=true`:

```xml
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message:raw=true}" />
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging

Answer (score 0):

Encountering the same problem, actually the only 'proper' and usable solution I found is to change the `NLog.config` to not show `${message}` but instead place the "human readable" message in a `${event-properties:message}`

With a `Logger` that is `ILogger` from Microsoft logging extension :

```
Logger.LogInformation("{message}{MyProperty1}{MyProperty2}","your message", "property1value", "property2value");
```

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="Log/${shortdate}_log.txt"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${event-properties:MyProperty1}|${event-properties:MyProperty2}|${event-properties:message}">
    </target>
</targets>
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/viktor-nikolaev/XeonApps.Extensions.Logging.WithProperty

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging#logtstate-simple (if you don't want an extra nuget-dependency)

Comment: @RolfKristensen thanks the extension library 'XeonApps.Extensions.Logging.withProperty' allow to pass extra properties without adding them diretly to the message ! tested just right now and its really nice :)